# Cannot upgrade or install new apps due to segmentation faults

Tags: 18.04

I am unable to upgrade or install new apps on Ubuntu 18.4; receive Segmentation Fault error; sometimes it reads Segmentation faultsts.  I tried to find postings, but most seem to indicate that more should be displayed in the error indicating what is causing the segmentation fault, like Core Dump, or something, but I don't get anything.  I'm new to linux and not sure how to troubleshoot further; where are log files kept that may show what may the underlying cause, and how to resolve.

**EDIT:** @heynnema Thanks for the assistance, below is the info you requested:

```
ls -al /var/crash

total 903536
drwxrwsrwt  2 root  whoopsie      4096 Nov 27 10:01 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root  root          4096 Jul 24  2018 ..
-rw-r-----  1 pablo whoopsie  12971216 Nov 27 10:02 _opt_google_chrome_chrome.1000.crash
-rw-r-----  1 root  whoopsie    649037 Nov 23 11:04 _usr_bin_apt.0.crash
-rw-r-----  1 root  whoopsie    641741 Nov 24 00:10 _usr_bin_apt-cache.0.crash
-rw-r-----  1 root  whoopsie    645751 Nov 22 06:23 _usr_bin_apt-get.0.crash
-rw-r-----  1 pablo whoopsie   3987966 Nov 25 10:20 _usr_lib_chromium-browser_chromium-browser.1000.crash
-rw-r-----  1 root  whoopsie   1062260 Nov 24 06:00 _usr_lib_packagekit_packagekitd.0.crash
-rw-r-----  1 pablo whoopsie   5074495 Nov 20 13:19 _usr_lib_ubuntu-release-upgrader_check-new-release-gtk.1000.crash
-rw-r-----  1 pablo whoopsie   3564261 Nov 21 14:22 _usr_lib_update-notifier_apt_check.py.1000.crash
-rw-r-----  1 root  whoopsie   6605029 Nov 23 10:48 _usr_sbin_aptd.0.crash
-rw-r-----  1 root  whoopsie   2587387 Nov 20 11:40 _usr_sbin_synaptic.0.crash
-rw-r-----  1 root  whoopsie 887400942 Nov 26 11:47 _usr_share_apport_whoopsie-upload-all.0.crash
```

```
free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           5.6G        2.4G        1.8G        239M        1.4G        2.7G
Swap:          979M        7.8M        972M
```

```
sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60
```

```
sudo lshw -C memory
  *-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: Acer
       physical id: 0
       version: V1.01
       date: 04/21/2011
       size: 1MiB
       capacity: 1984KiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppynec int13floppytoshiba int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int9keyboard int10video acpi usb
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 24
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 6GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1066 MHz (0.9 ns)
          product: HMT351S6CFR8C-H9
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 0
          serial: 2C837472
          slot: DIMM0
          size: 4GiB
          width: 8 bits
          clock: 1066MHz (0.9ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1066 MHz (0.9 ns)
          product: ACR256X64D3S1333C9
          vendor: Kinston
          physical id: 1
          serial: 670A270A
          slot: DIMM1
          size: 2GiB
          width: 8 bits
          clock: 1066MHz (0.9ns)
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 2e
       slot: L1 Cache
       size: 128KiB
       capacity: 128KiB
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 2f
       slot: L2 Cache
       size: 1MiB
       capacity: 1MiB
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2

grep -i swap /etc/fstab
pablo@pablo-Aspire-5250:~$ grep -i swap /etc/fstab
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al /var/crash` and `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `sudo lshw -C memory` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema They didn't ping you, and I am going through older questions and I noticed it. So, I pinged you for them. One thing I did notice is the mismatched RAM. Dunno if that matters, but it's unusual.

Comment: @KGIII Thanks for the follow up! Their memory configuration is not optimized for memory interleaving (by using matching SODIMMs), but it's ok. I'll have them run `memtest` to make sure there's not a bad SODIMM... which is what this sounds like.

Comment: Paul, whenever you respond to a request for more information, be sure to notify the requester by sending a comment that starts with @heynnema (using myself as an example). Otherwise we'll miss your updates.

Comment: Paul, tell me the EXACT model # of your Acer.

Comment: @heynnema, thanks for your help, sorry, I"m not clear on the protocol here.  My laptop is an Aspire 5250

Comment: @heynnema: thanks for your assistance; I learned that I could only update the BIOS from a windows OS; I did find some posts on how to do it from linux, but it involved downloading utilities-- and I'm unable to load anything new (get the segmentation errors).  And when I tried to load a Windows OS, I ran into issues since the disk wasn't properly formatted for Windows.  I did have an old desktop, so I updated the BIOS on that, and then I put Ubuntu20 on it, and it seems to be working out fine.  But I really appreciate you taking the time to answer my questions.

Comment: @PaulH Did you run memtest? Many times a DOS USB flash key will work for upgrading the BIOS. Also some machines can update using the existing BIOS.

Comment: @heynnema; yes I ran memtest on the laptop, a couple of times and it passed without issue.  I will look more into flashing the BIOS.

Comment: @PaulH Did you run memtest all the way through? How long did it run for?

Comment: @heynnema; yes I ran memtest a couple of times; each time took a couple of hours.

Comment: @PaulH Figure out some way to update the BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

**memtest**

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

Note: Because you're using different size/type SODIMMs, you're not taking advantage of the speed improvement that comes with using memory interleaving.

**BIOS**

Acer Aspire 5250

You have BIOS 1.01, dated 04/21/2011.

There's a newer BIOS available, version 1.08, and can be downloaded [here](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/support-product/3677?b=1).

Note: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your model #.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.